# RedBoot stops booting on any input

Tags: arm, embedded, bootloader

There's a problem with bootloader of my embedded board. Sometimes it fails to boot after restart.

The problem has been tracked down to RedBoot, which waits (0.1s) for "ctrl-C" to abort booting and enter interactive mode where you can edit it. The problem is that while a randomly occurring "ctrl-C" character on unconnected serial console is extremely unlikely, *any, random* character is sometimes induced "out of air", and then RedBoot stops at the prompt "== Executing boot script in 0.100 seconds - enter ^C to abort" until either one presses enter, deletes the offending character (with backspace) or enters RedBoot with ctrl-C.

Is there some way to disable this "feature" without disabling ability to reach the "RedBoot>" prompt entirely?

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware issue really - input pins really shouldn't be left floating such that 'data' can magically appear out of thin air. I'd double check that the pull-up/pull-down configuration is correct.

Comment: There seem to be two issues here - where you are getting characters, and why *anything* works and not just ctrl-C.  The latter sounds like a mismatch between the instruction message, and the actual code...

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The characters - on "free-hanging" RS232 "just happen", there are currently hundreds deployed devices and the problem only appeared like 2-3 times in the past years. The device is fairly well shielded from EMI but you just can't avoid all of it. Now why RedBoot works like that, this is beyond me...

Comment: Have you looked at the source code yet? I still think you should try to quiet the electrical noise, but you can make the process of getting into the bootloader multi-step, with a timeout to normal boot in all the steps are not completed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The problem is on a 3rd party board, so there's not much we can do electronics-wise. And I'm really reluctant about touching the sources of RedBoot - replacing it on that board is a mess, I already bricked one trying to do it. After some deliberation the solution I came up with is disabling the console for boot with a jumper. Linux can use it anyway, and so far in field service I had to use RedBoot exactly once - so if the necessity occurs, I'll replace the jumper. (it's awfully inconveniently placed, necessitating dismantling half of the board, but it's very rarely needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old thread, but I just encountered exactly the same problem. In my case it is because the Redboot console serial port is tied to another embedded Windows system that is powered up at the same time. A short burst of noise on the serial port in that scenario is always guaranteed and Redboot would always get stuck as described by the original question!

My fix was quite simple - in `main.c`, function `cyg_start()`:

```
diff --git a/packages/redboot/current/src/main.c b/packages/redboot/current/src/main.c
index 0531dcc..9b1ce97 100644
--- a/packages/redboot/current/src/main.c
+++ b/packages/redboot/current/src/main.c
@@ -356,26 +356,11 @@ cyg_start(void)
 # endif
     if (script) {
         // Give the guy a chance to abort any boot script
-        char *hold_script = script;
         int script_timeout_ms = script_timeout * CYGNUM_REDBOOT_BOOT_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT_RESOLUTION;
         diag_printf("== Executing boot script in %d.%03d seconds - enter ^C to abort\n", 
                     script_timeout_ms/1000, script_timeout_ms%1000);
-        script = NULL;
-        res = _GETS_CTRLC;  // Treat 0 timeout as ^C
-        while (script_timeout_ms >= CYGNUM_REDBOOT_CLI_IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
-            res = _rb_gets(line, sizeof(line), CYGNUM_REDBOOT_CLI_IDLE_TIMEOUT);
-            if (res >= _GETS_OK) {
-                diag_printf("== Executing boot script in %d.%03d seconds - enter ^C to abort\n", 
-                            script_timeout_ms/1000, script_timeout_ms%1000);
-                continue;  // Ignore anything but ^C
-            }
-            if (res != _GETS_TIMEOUT) break;
-            script_timeout_ms -= CYGNUM_REDBOOT_CLI_IDLE_TIMEOUT;
-        }
-        if (res == _GETS_CTRLC) {
+        if (_rb_break(script_timeout_ms)) {
             script = NULL;  // Disable script
-        } else {
-            script = hold_script;  // Re-enable script
         }
     }
 #endif
```

CTRL-C is still able to be used to abort the boot script if required, but any other character (including a spurious character created by noise) is interpreted immediately as a timeout. In my scenario this is perfect as the only time you would want to be able to type CTRL-C is if you manually reset the Redboot board and has a serial console open on the embedded Windows system to watch what was happening.